# Delta Query with delta token: Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am working on change notifications for users using Microsoft Graph SDK in a .netcore application.
I am using delta query to get the latest changes.

```
private static IUserDeltaCollectionPage? lastPage = null;
private async Task<IUserDeltaCollectionPage> GetUsers(GraphServiceClient graphClient, object? deltaLink)
{
  IUserDeltaCollectionPage page;

  if (lastPage == null || deltaLink == null)
  {
    page = await graphClient.Users
                            .Delta()
                            .Request()
                            .GetAsync();
  }
  else
  {
    lastPage.InitializeNextPageRequest(graphClient, deltaLink.ToString());
    page = await lastPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
  }

  lastPage = page;
  return page;
}
```

The problem I am facing with this approach is that, if the application restarts for what ever reason the `lastPage` will be null. In which case the next time the application runs it will bring back all the users. I don't want to get all the users, I just want to get the changed users.

Is there a way to make a delta query with the latest delta link?

I tried the below but I am getting badly formed query error.

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
                    {
                        new QueryOption("$deltatoken", deltaLink?.ToString())
                    };

await graphClient.Users.Delta().Request(options).GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for the latest `deltaLink` by adding `$deltaToken=latest` to the delta function and the response will contain a `deltaLink` and no resource data.

Then you need to use received `deltaLink`

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("$deltatoken", "latest")
};

var page = await graphClient.Groups.Delta().Request(options).GetAsync();
var users = page.CurrentPage.ToList();
if (page.NextPageRequest!=null)
{
    // get latest data
    page = await page.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
}
```

Resources:

[delta query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#use-delta-query-to-track-changes-in-a-resource-collection)

Comment: thank you. But this will be for the first request, right? What will it be for the next request? Next time the application is called?If we then use the latest then we will not get any updates?Because it is sync from now?

Comment: @Newbie What exactly is deltaLink in your code? Is it delta token?